# Can we use energy density to calculate mutual potential energy

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

I know that point charge particle's energy calculated by energy density is infinity. But can we use it to calculate mutual potential energy?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can !

${{E}_{\operatorname{int}}}=\iiint{\frac{{{\overrightarrow{E}}_{1}}(P){{\overrightarrow{E}}_{2}}(P)}{{{\varepsilon }_{0}}}}d\tau $ with ${{\overrightarrow{E}}_{1}}(P)=\frac{{{q}_{1}}}{4\pi {{\varepsilon }_{0}}}\frac{\overrightarrow{OP}}{O{{P}^{3}}}$ and ${{\overrightarrow{E}}_{2}}(P)=\frac{{{q}_{1}}}{4\pi {{\varepsilon }_{0}}}\frac{\overrightarrow{{{O}_{2}}P}}{{{O}_{2}}{{P}^{3}}}$
If the first charge is in $O$ and the second in $O2$.

The computation may be done in spherical coordinates with origin O and axe OO2.
$\overrightarrow{{{O}_{2}}P}=\overrightarrow{{{O}_{2}}O}+\overrightarrow{OP}$ and so ${{\overrightarrow{{{O}_{2}}P}}^{2}}={{\overrightarrow{{{O}_{2}}O}}^{2}}+{{\overrightarrow{OP}}^{2}}+2\overrightarrow{{{O}_{2}}O}\centerdot \overrightarrow{OP}={{d}^{2}}+{{r}^{2}}-2dr\cos (\theta )$....

I let you finish the computation !